# Why is 'assert' not considered as a function of type bool->unit, but a keyword?

Tags: ocaml, internals

I do not follow why `assert` is not considered as a function of type `bool -> unit`, but a keyword.

```
# assert (2=2) ;;
- : unit = ()
# assert;;
Line 1, characters 6-8:
Error: Syntax error
```

Comment: How would you implement `-noassert`, including non-evaluation, if it was "just" a function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is required by the two-words keyword:

```
assert false
```

which has type `'a` rather than `unit`.

This is especially useful when using `assert false` to mock function

```
let not_yet_implemented _ = assert false
```

or when stating that a branch of a pattern matching is unreachable due to an invariant:

```ml
let f = function
| A | B as x ->
  begin match x with
  | A -> 1
  | B -> 2
  | C -> assert false
  end
| C -> 2
```